# Exercises - "From calculus to cohomology"

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes

I am reading Madsen's book [From calculus to cohomology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521589568) and I've found it doesn't have any (explicit) exercises at the end of each section. I'd like to know a few books where I can find some problems so that I can delve into the topics and expand a little bit the theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exercises aren't at the end of each section, but they're all at the end of the book in Appendix D.

Comment: I can't believe it!! Thank you so much for letting me know this. :-)

Comment: No trouble at all!  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Precisely Milnor - Stasheff, 1974's **"Characteristic Classes"** a super clasic.

Safe: **[Link](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnstas.pdf)**

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any other in mind?

Comment: this: *From Calculus to Cohomology: De Rham Cohomology and Characteristic Classes* of Madsen - Tornehave

Comment: That is the one I am reading.

Comment: *Differential forms in Algebraic topology* of Bott - Tu.